# Redux useSelector hook always return an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a react component like this, where I have a websocket set up, and on websocket events I am trying to update state inside of Redux

```js
const Body = () => {
    // Hook for Redux dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // REDUX reducers
    const workCenterAvailabilityQueue = useSelector(selectAllWorkCenterAvailabilities)

    // Add or Update workCenterAvailability
    let existingWorkCenter;
    const workCenterAvailabilityHandler = (id, data) => {
        console.log('id = ', id)
        console.log('data = ', data)
        console.log(workCenterAvailabilityQueue)

        existingWorkCenter = workCenterAvailabilityQueue.find(bm => bm.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID === id);
        console.log(existingWorkCenter)

        if (existingWorkCenter) {
            console.log('WorkCenter exists, updating data!')
            dispatch(updateWorkCenterAvailability({
                id: existingWorkCenter.id,
                changes: { Connection_Status: data.Connection_Status }})
            );
        }
        else {
            console.log('WorkCenter does not exist, creating one!')
            dispatch(addWorkCenterAvailability(data));

        }
    }

    // Debugging
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Updated state:', workCenterAvailabilityQueue);
        if(workCenterAvailabilityQueue[10]){
            console.log('workCenterAvailabilityQueue[10] -> ', workCenterAvailabilityQueue[10])
        }
        console.log('\n')
    }, [workCenterAvailabilityQueue]);

    // Web Socket setup
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('connecting to Flask socket')
        const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

        console.log('Start listening')
        socket.on('workCenterAvailability', (data) => {
            workCenterAvailabilityHandler(data.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID, data)
        });

        console.log('emitting message')
        socket.emit('requestWorkCenterAvailability');
        console.log('emitted!')

        // Clean up function
        return () => {
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    }, []);
```

So my problem is that when I try to use the handler function, the `workCenterAvailabilityQueue` always come back as an empty array, so when I try to find an object in the Queue it always fails

However based on the useEffect hook I have all the way at the bottom for debugging purposes, I can see that each time I add something to the Queue, it is in fact added to Redux

Why does my `workCenterAvailabilityQueue` not contain live information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `useEffect` hook calls `workCenterAvailabilityHandler` in a `"workCenterAvailability"` event callback handler, which has a stale Javascript closure over the selected `workCenterAvailabilityQueue` state.

You can resolve this issue a couple of ways:

1. Import the store object and get the current state value in the `workCenterAvailabilityHandler` callback handler.

   ```js
   import store from '../path/to/store';

   ...

   // Add or Update workCenterAvailability
   const workCenterAvailabilityHandler = (id, data) => {
     const state = store.getState();
     const const workCenterAvailabilityQueue = 
       selectAllWorkCenterAvailabilities(state);

     const existingWorkCenter = workCenterAvailabilityQueue.find(
       bm => bm.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID === id
     );

     if (existingWorkCenter) {
       dispatch(updateWorkCenterAvailability({
         id: existingWorkCenter.id,
         changes: { Connection_Status: data.Connection_Status }
       }));
     } else {
       dispatch(addWorkCenterAvailability(data));
     }
   };

   ...

   // Web Socket setup
   useEffect(() => {
     const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

     socket.on('workCenterAvailability', (data) => {
       workCenterAvailabilityHandler(data.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID, data)
     });

     socket.emit('requestWorkCenterAvailability');

     // Clean up function
     return () => {
       socket.disconnect();
     };
   }, []);

   ...
   ```
2. Use a React ref to cache the current `workCenterAvailabilityQueue` state value.

   ```js
   ...

   const workCenterAvailabilityQueue = useSelector(
     selectAllWorkCenterAvailabilities
   );

   const workCenterAvailabilityQueueRef = React.useRef();

   useEffect(() => {
     workCenterAvailabilityQueueRef.current = workCenterAvailabilityQueue;
   }, [workCenterAvailabilityQueue]);

   ...

       // Add or Update workCenterAvailability
   const workCenterAvailabilityHandler = (id, data) => {
     const const workCenterAvailabilityQueue = 
       workCenterAvailabilityQueueRef.current;

     const existingWorkCenter = workCenterAvailabilityQueue.find(
       bm => bm.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID === id
     );

     if (existingWorkCenter) {
       dispatch(updateWorkCenterAvailability({
         id: existingWorkCenter.id,
         changes: { Connection_Status: data.Connection_Status }
       }));
     } else {
       dispatch(addWorkCenterAvailability(data));
     }
   };

   // Web Socket setup
   useEffect(() => {
     const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

     socket.on('workCenterAvailability', (data) => {
       workCenterAvailabilityHandler(data.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID, data)
     });

     socket.emit('requestWorkCenterAvailability');

     // Clean up function
     return () => {
       socket.disconnect();
     };
   }, []);

   ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the ref approach because it's simpler, very much appreciated!!